# WooCommerce get cart information from postmeta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have written a function that should add discount amounts on the woo cart, depends on product combination and custom fields.
If the action is `wp_footer` i can see `get_post_meta` works well.
But if I write action to be `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` seems not to work fine.

Can anyone help me with getting into the right direction? Thanks
Here is my code and screenshot below for it:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees2');
function action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees2($cart)  {
  //  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
       // return;
    
    //if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 1 )
        //return;

//$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    foreach ( $cart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        //echo $product_id . "<br>";
    
        $is_enable = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_enable_promo_for_current_product', true );
        if ($is_enable == 'yes') {
            $product_arr[] = $product_id;
        }
    }
    foreach ( $product_arr as $val ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($val);
        
        $otstapka = get_post_meta( $val, '_procent_otstapka_promo', true );
    
        if (empty($otstapka)) {
            $otstapka = 10;
        }
        
        $value = get_post_meta( $val, 'wc_product_ids', true );
        
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $promo_product = wc_get_product( $value );
            $name = $promo_product->name;
            $price = $promo_product->get_price();
            $sale_price = $price * (1 - ($otstapka / 100));
            $otstapka2 = $price - $sale_price;
            $product_promo_id = $promo_product->get_id();
                    
            if ( check_variation_is_in_cart($val) ) {
                $cart->add_fee('Отстъпка за промо пакет', -$otstapka2, false);
            }
        }
    }
    

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is `check_variation_is_in_cart($val)`

Comment: It's connected product id

Comment: Does it return a boolean, or a value? If it's not a boolean, then your condition is always false, and it will never update the cart.

Comment: No matter. I cannot use get_post_meta